# What does try after the parameter list of a constructor mean?

Tags: c++, syntax, try-catch, member-initialization

I have seen the peculiar syntax in an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574995/its-so-weird-an-exception-were-caught-two-times) a while ago.

```
class B{
    A a;
    public:
        B() try : a() {} catch(string& s) { cout << &s << " " << s << endl; };
};
```

What is the meaning of this try-catch-block outside the function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's function try block. Usefull only in c-tors for catch errors in derived classes constructors. You can read more about this feature in standard for example n3337 draft par. 15, 15.1.

> 4 A function-try-block associates a handler-seq with the
>   ctor-initializer, if present, and the compound-statement. An exception
>   thrown during the execution of the compound-statement or, for
>   constructors and destructors, during the initialization or
>   destruction, respectively, of the class’s subobjects, transfers
>   control to a handler in a function-try-block in the same way as an
>   exception thrown during the execution of a try-block transfers control
>   to other handlers. [ Example:

```
int f(int);
class C {
int i;
double d;
public:
C(int, double);
};
C::C(int ii, double id)
try : i(f(ii)), d(id) {
// constructor statements
}
catch (...) {
// handles exceptions thrown from the ctor-initializer
// and from the constructor statements
}
```

> —end example ]

Comment: See http://www.drdobbs.com/introduction-to-function-try-blocks/184401297 for a more in-depth explanation and rationale.

Comment: @PermanentGuest this feature used rarely, since at the end of your catch block exception will be rethrown, if you not throw some other exception. function-try-block cannot take up exception.

Answer (score 0):

It catches exceptions thrown from a constructor when creating a member object. One of the answers to the question you mentioned contains a link explaining the details: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm.